# Sofia SIP build for i386/armv7

Tags: ios, static-libraries, armv7, i386, sofia-sip

my last question was too unspecific I think. 
 
So my next is better.\

How can I compile the Sofia-Sip library for i386 and amrv7 ? 
 
Would be great to get an answer !

Thank you fellows, 
 
Alexander Heinrich

Answer (score 3):

For everybody who wants to save a  lot of time in compiling sofia sip for iPhone / iPhone Simulator. 
 Here are some hints:

You have to use the llvm-gcc compiler found in Xcode 4.6 under /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/bin/llvm-gcc

This should compile sofia sip for iPhone if you add some flags for architecture and so on.

At the moment I'm working on a Script which should compile everything. 
When I'm finished I'll edit my answer and post the script.

I hope that could help some of you a bit

Comment: @SnOwfreeze Can you please explain in detail how you compiled SofiaSip. I am facing similar problem and trying to resolve it since long. Request you to help

Comment: i cant able to compile sofia library and dont know the procedure how to include it in xcode project

Comment: can you please guide me !

Comment: Actually we changed to PJSIP and we are currently trying to use Gossip: https://github.com/chakrit/gossip